# How to access a button and do some work when clicked in ListView ItemTemplate from code behinde?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, button, click

.aspx

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListViewUsers" ItemType="User" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListViewUsers_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="center">
                                <table id="tableUsers">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><%#Item.UserName%></td>
                                        <td><asp:Button ID="Btn_addFriend"
                                             runat="server"  Text="Add friend" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                                   ...
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void ListViewUsers_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      // How to access the button, and do some work when it is clicked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is to add CommandName argument to Your button and later catch this inside Your EventHandler. Example below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_addFriend" runat="server"  Text="Add friend" CommandName="Add friend" />
```

Now You can catch this command in Your event handler like this:

```
protected void ListViewUsers_ItemCommand(object sender,ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Add friend"))
  {
    // ... DO SOME WORK HERE
  }
}
```

Referring to MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx